# Multiple comparisons after GLM including interaction terms

Tags: r, glm, interaction, tukey

I am analizing a dataset of participants binary answers to certain questions. I am using the `glm` function to test how do `Var * Base_con` affect the outcome of `Dec`. After the fit, I am trying to compare how the "Var" factor affects outcome within each of the "Base_con" factor levels. Following [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/multcomp-examples.pdf), I have tried the following (failing) approach, which I believe can be reproduced (please let me know if it does not work):

```
# load example dataset with relevant columns
require(RCurl)
my_csv = getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sBVW7QbnfumeRmY1uEDdiDNJE7QfmCXH0wMmV2lZSH4/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv")
eg_data = read.csv(textConnection(my_csv))
# set columns as factors because they are numerically coded
eg_data$Base_con = as.factor(eg_data$Base_con)
eg_data$Var = as.factor(eg_data$Var)
eg_data$Dec = as.factor(eg_data$Dec)

# GLM fit
m1 = glm(Dec ~ Var * Base_con, data = eg_data, family = "binomial")

# strategy for Tukey multiple comparisons
require(multcomp)
tmp = expand.grid(Base_con = unique(eg_data$Base_con), Var = unique(eg_data$Var))
X = model.matrix(~Base_con : Var, data = tmp)
mc = glht(m1, linfct = X)
```

The output for the last command is:

```
Error in glht.matrix(m1, linfct = X) : 
  ‘ncol(linfct)’ is not equal to ‘length(coef(model))’
```

In effect, the number of columns and length of the two elements reported by the error message are different:

```
> ncol(X)
[1] 7
> length(coef(m1))
[1] 6
```

That is all I have been able to advance so far. Any ideas? Thanks to all.

Comment: Note that the `lme4` package does *not* have a `glm` function; `glm()` is in the base package. If you have multiple responses per participant, you presumably need to use `glmer`.

Comment: @gung, you're right. It's the basic `glm` function. This time there are no repeated measures, so it is not necessary to use `glmer`.
@Silverfish, I will try to edit using a reproducible example, although I am not sure I will be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: If *you* can't reproduce the error, @Lea_Casiraghi, how would *we* be able to? & how would we be able to find a solution w/o reproducing the error?

Comment: @gung: I meant that I was not sure it could be reproduced until someone tries it. The edit above should work for anyone to try it. Thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to compare effects for interactions of `Base_con` and `Var`, a more direct way may be to create a new term for these interactions (here I've changed the dataframe name to `d`):

```
d$BV <- interaction(d$Base_con, d$Var)
```

Then fit the model and do the comparisons:

```
# GLM fit
m1  <- glm(Dec ~ -1 + BV, data = d, family = "binomial")

library(multcomp)
summary(glht(m1, linfct = mcp(BV = "Tukey")))

    #    Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

    # Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


    # Fit: glm(formula = Dec ~ -1 + BV, family = "binomial", data = d)

    # Linear Hypotheses:
    #                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    # 2.0 - 1.0 == 0  -1.7988     0.4632  -3.883  0.00133 ** 
    # 3.0 - 1.0 == 0  -4.9702     0.4846 -10.255  < 0.001 ***
    # 1.1 - 1.0 == 0  -1.6596     0.4523  -3.669  0.00308 ** 
    # 2.1 - 1.0 == 0  -3.0593     0.4392  -6.965  < 0.001 ***
    # 3.1 - 1.0 == 0  -5.3893     0.4759 -11.325  < 0.001 ***
    # 3.0 - 2.0 == 0  -3.1714     0.3190  -9.941  < 0.001 ***
    # 1.1 - 2.0 == 0   0.1392     0.2673   0.521  0.99498    
    # 2.1 - 2.0 == 0  -1.2605     0.2446  -5.154  < 0.001 ***
    # 3.1 - 2.0 == 0  -3.5905     0.3055 -11.751  < 0.001 ***
    # 1.1 - 3.0 == 0   3.3106     0.3029  10.930  < 0.001 ***
    # 2.1 - 3.0 == 0   1.9109     0.2830   6.751  < 0.001 ***
    # 3.1 - 3.0 == 0  -0.4191     0.3371  -1.243  0.80488    
    # 2.1 - 1.1 == 0  -1.3997     0.2231  -6.273  < 0.001 ***
    # 3.1 - 1.1 == 0  -3.7297     0.2887 -12.920  < 0.001 ***
    # 3.1 - 2.1 == 0  -2.3300     0.2678  -8.702  < 0.001 ***
    # ---
    # Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    # (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Comment: I could reproduce that result but I have no idea of what it means, or what is it comparing.

Comment: There should be 6 Var and Base_con combinations, and hence a total of 15 possible comparisons, and three comparisons between Var values within the Base_con levels. I am not sure what is it testing here, or why it is not working in my example.

Comment: The comparison here is e.g. `Var0:Base_con1 == 0`, i.e a test of difference from 0.  If you want to compare effects, you'll have to set `X` up differently.  I'll see if I can put something up when I get a couple of minutes.

Comment: OK. In this case I don't think that test has any utility, because what I want to compare is the change of frequencies of `Dec` 1 and 0 answers between combinations. It'd be great if you can come up with a way to test that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The revised answer should address your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you help me understand a little more of what you did? Why does the new `glm` model only include the interaction column? Why is there a `-1` term in the model? Are these multiple comparisons compatible with the original model (i.e. can I report results from both analysis)? Thanks again.